# Cannot construct the correct query WHERE clause - Composite keys, multiple tables, full data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

We have a rather long-winded Query, and cannot get it to work "correctly".
The Query and requirements are listed below.

Apologies if the Title of this question is not much help. We did not know what else to name it.

Current code :

```
from process in _db.Process
  join job in _db.Job on new { Company_ID = process.Company_ID, Job_ID = process.Job_ID } equals new { Company_ID = job.Company_ID, Job_ID = job.ID } into j
  from subjob in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join pp in _db.Process on new { Company_ID = process.Company_ID, ParentProcess_ID = process.ParentProcess_ID } equals new { Company_ID = pp.Company_ID, ParentProcess_ID = pp.ID } into p
  from subprocess in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where process.Company_ID = Company_ID
  && process.IsActive == true
  // issue is with the following 2 lines of code
  //&& (j == null ? true : subjob.IsActive == true)
  ///&& (p == null ? true : subprocess.IsActive == true)
  select new ProcessIndexView { ID = process.ID, DescShort = process.DescShort, Job_ID = process.Job_ID, ParentProcess_ID = process.ParentProcess_ID, JobValue = (subjob == null ? "(no parent Job for this Process)" : subjob.DescShort), ParentProcessValue = (subprocess == null ? "(no parent Process for this Process)" : subprocess.DescShort ) }).ToList();
```

Query requirements :

> 1. There is a Company_ID field that occurs across all tables. All logic must be within the same Company_ID value.
> 2. process.Job_ID : A [Process] "may" have a "parent" [Job], or it may be ZERO (0).
> 3. process.ParentProcess_ID : A [Process] "may" have a "parent" [Process] (within the [Job], if present), or it may be ZERO (0).
> 4. The [Process].IsActive *MUST* be TRUE.
> 5. WHEN there is a "parent" [Job], [Job].IsActive *MUST* be TRUE. Otherwise, the parent is not active so this child should also not be active.
>      Note here that we DO NOT want to update the [Process].IsActive value when the "parent" [Job].IsActive value is updated, due to other system logics.
> 6. WHEN there is a "parent" [Process], [Process].IsActive *MUST* be TRUE. Otherwise, the parent is not active so this child should also not be active.
>      Note here that we DO NOT want to update the [Process].IsActive value when the "parent" [Process].IsActive value is updated, due to other system logics.
> 7. Our data *DOES* contain ALL "valid" data values - zeroes, Active = True and False, etc.

When we un-comment the two commented-out lines in the query, we get the error :

> {"Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported."}

This is "because there is a NULL check in the WHERE clause, according to other StackOverflow Questions.
When we comment out those two lines (as provided above), and reduce the data to a "nice" subset, the Query is OK. However, this fails our requirements # 5, 6, and 7 - so is not a valid resolution.

Is there a different way to (re)structure our query ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should *really* reformat that code so that you don't have so much horizontal scrolling.  It makes it a nightmare to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` and `p` will never be `null`, ever, due to the way LINQ is implemented.  They may be *empty*, but they won't be *null*.

If you want to indicate that the rows should be included if `j` and be are either non-empty, or the corresponding boolean is active, then you need to indicate *that*:

```
where process.Company_ID == Company_ID //note this probably shouldn't be assignment
    && process.IsActive
    && (!j.Any() || subjob.IsActive)
    && (!p.Any() || subprocess.IsActive)
```

Comment: To @Servy, Thank you for your quick response. Instead of "non-empty" in your Answer, we want "... are either empty, or the corresponding Boolean is active". When `j` or `p` are *empty*, then the record is OK. So we want `j.Empty` or similar, else .IsActive.  What is the `.Empty` part ?

Comment: @and_E A set is empty if it doesn't have any items.  There is already a method to see if a set has any items, you just need to call it, and negate it, and then you're done, you know that the set is empty.

Comment: oh, n00b mis-read of your answer !  This is perfect - `!j.Any()` and `!p.Any()` , noting the `!` for "negate it". Tested and works well. Wonderful - Thank you @Servy.